# Перевод текста в двоичный код PHP

Tags: php, php7, системы-счисления

Как можно перевести текст в двоичный код?

Пробовал так, он переводит, но как то криво, в отличии от decbin:

```
$x = "abc12345";
$x = base_convert($x, 16, 2);
echo $x;
```

---

И если decbin работает как надо, почему base_convert работает непонятно как?
на [официальной странице](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.base-convert.php) есть пример показывающий работу

Пример #1 Пример использования base_convert()

```
<?php
$hexadecimal = 'a37334';
echo base_convert($hexadecimal, 16, 2);
?>
```

Результат выполнения данного примера:

```
101000110111001100110100
```

Сравнил две функции:

```
<?
$x = "abc12345";

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($x); $i++) {
    echo decbin(ord($x[$i])) . "";
}
echo "<br>";
$y = "abc12345";
$y = base_convert($y, 16, 2);
echo $y;
?>
```

Результат выполнения:

```
110000111000101100011110001110010110011110100110101

10101011110000010010001101000101
```

От чего такая разница?

> base_convert — Преобразовывает числа между произвольными системами счисления
>
> decbin — Переводит число из десятичной системы счисления в двоичную
>
> ord - Возвращает ASCII код символа

Самое интересно в том что если сделать так

```
<?
$x = "abc12345";
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($x); $i++) {
    echo decbin(ord($x[$i]));
}

$y = "abc12345";
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($y); $i++) {
    echo base_convert(ord($y[$i]), 10, 2);
}
?>
```

Результат будет одинаковым:

```
110000111000101100011110001110010110011110100110101
110000111000101100011110001110010110011110100110101
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> base_convert — Преобразовывает **числа** между произвольными системами счисления

`abc12345` - это корректное шестнадцатеричное *число* из 4 байт, эквивалент 2881561413 в десятичной системе счисления.

В то же время циклом с вызовом `ord` по строке вы обрабатываете значение не как число, а как массив *строковых* байт. Так, символ `a` - это байт `\x61` (но только для ASCII-совместимых кодировок! Может быть иначе). Затем вы некорректно собираете результирующую строку, теряя ведущие нули результата. И потому получаете последовательность из некорректных 51 бит вместо 64:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($x); $i++) {
    echo str_pad(decbin(ord($x[$i])), 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

0110000101100010011000110011000100110010001100110011010000110101
```

Почему 64 бита? Потому что в ASCII *строке* `abc12345` всего 8 байт, каждый символ закодирован значением в 8 бит. Но в 16-ричном *числе* `abc12345` только 4 байта, потому что одна 16-ричная цифра кодирует 4 бита информации. Вы преобразуете на самом деле разные исходные данные и потому получаете различный результат. Вот такое малое различие, которое может быть непонятно для языка с мягкой динамической типизацией, но крайне важное.

Comment: с этим все понятно @Эдуард уже дал верное решение,  а почему именно base_convert($y, 16, 2) дает совсем другие данные, т.е. мы переводим из шестнадцатеричного в двоичное, и так же с decbin по вашему примеру мы перевели в двоичный код, но результат разный

Comment: Так именно это я и объяснил. Один пример конвертирует число, другой строку. Это разные данные и результат разумеется будет разный.

Comment: и какой из них тогда верный двоичный код? если они по разному конвертируют

Comment: система исчисления одна и таже, а код разный

Comment: Верны и 32-битный и 64-битный результат. Потому что, повторюсь в очередной раз, вы кодируете _разные_ данные.

Comment: все понял) хвост феи рулит)

Answer (score 1):

```
$x = "abc12345";

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($x); $i++) {
    echo decbin(ord($x[$i])) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: т.е. если не будет пробелов обратно его не раскодировать так?

Comment: пользовался сторонними сервисам типо https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/binary-to-ascii.html

Comment: ок с обраткой понятно, я тупанул) а почему такие расхождения в функциях  base_convert  и  decbin?